# Harmonic conjugate on a simply connected domain existence proof with the skew-gradient

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, vector-fields

I am a physics student following some notes on complex analysis, specifically their relation to harmonic functions. There is a proof that every harmonic function defined on a simply connected domain has a harmonic conjugate that forms, with it, an analytic complex function on the same domain (or so I understand). The proof involves using the skew-gradient
$$\nabla v=\nabla^{\perp}u\tag{1},$$
with
$$\nabla^{\perp}=\begin{pmatrix}-\partial_y \\ \partial_x\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}.$$
We then use the fact that a potential function exists for $\nabla^{\perp}u$ iff a line integral in the domain is path independent. The following step does something that confuses me:
$$0=\oint_\mathcal{C}\vec\nabla v\cdot d\vec x=\oint_\mathcal{C}\vec\nabla^{\perp}u\cdot d\vec x=\oint_\mathcal{C}\vec \nabla u\cdot \vec n\text{ }ds.$$
The last step is confusing to me, we are saying that any closed integral must be $0$. We then take the closed integral of the gradient field of the function $v$ around $\mathcal{C}$. This is equal to the skew-gradient field of $u$, that makes sense since they're the same thing by definition. But in the last step we introduce a new vector $\vec n$, which I assume is some normal vector, but to which direction?
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: $\vec{n}$ is the vector normal to the contour (which we must assume to sastisfy some smoothness requirement, otherwise the normal is undefined). One easy way to define it, for example, is thanks to the arc-length parametrization of the contour. In fact, let $\gamma(t)$ be the a.l. parametrization of the contour. Then $\frac{\gamma''(t)}{||\gamma''(t)||}$ is the normal vector.